# Assigning character values to numeric variables

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS. I have been reading the SAS Certification Review Base Programming book and came across the following example and question that confuse me.

[image]

The top page is the example. I am confused as the `first` array is an array defined to contain 3 numeric variables, instead in the output each element in the `first` array contains character values. How is that possible?

The bottom page is a question related to the example, the correct answer is C and I do not understand why.

I know the the default byte size for a numeric variable is 8 bytes but `newfirst` array is an array containing 3 character variables which do not have default sizes.

Any suggestion or comment is welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
array first [3] ;
```

says nothing about what types of variables that array FIRST is used to reference.

It is just short hand for one of these array statements:

```
array first first1 first2 first3 ;
array first first1-first3 ;
```

Saving you the trouble of listing the variable names that the array will be used to reference.

So if FIRST1 to FIRST3 already exist when SAS sees the ARRAY statement those variables are used in the array.

Since that data step has a SET statement we can assume that FIRST1 to FIRST3 already existed in the dataset NAMES so they will be defined in this new data step before the ARRAY statement is seen.

Similarly the second array statement

```
array newfirst [3] $7 ;
```

will only define NEWFIRST1 to NEWFIRST3 as length $7 if the do not already exist.  If they do exist then the $7 is ignored as their type and length has already been set.

I suspect you are confused because SAS will create NEW variables if you mention them.  And if there is not specific information for it to guess a particular type for the variable it will guess NUMERIC.

This is not unique to ARRAY statements. Using variables first in an assignment statements, INPUT statement, FORMAT statements and others will also have the same **side effect** of forcing SAS to make a guess about what type (and length for character variables) you intended them to be.

Answer (score 0):

The statement in the first slide "if an array is based on new character variables, the elements must be defined as character with a byte size" is clearly false, because the example on the second slide will run without errors.  In fact you can use an ARRAY statement to create new character variables, without specifying a byte size, e.g.:

```
data have ;
  array foo{3} $ ;
run ;
proc contents ;
run ;
```

That will return:

Alphabetic List of Variables and Attributes

```
#    Variable    Type    Len

1    foo1        Char      8
2    foo2        Char      8
3    foo3        Char      8
```

So basically you didn't specify a length for the variables created by the ARRAY statement, so SAS went with a default length, and apparently 8 is the default.

Generally it's a good idea to specify the length of character variables when you create them, because depending on how you create them, SAS can choose different default lengths (8, 200, 32767...).